# How to make Eclipse interpret a file as xhtml?

Tags: html, eclipse, xhtml

I am working with Eclipse Neon and would like to make Eclipse interpret (syntax highlight and error check) files with a certain (yet arbitrary) file name extension as XHTML files.

I have found the following related configuration places:

```
Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations
Preferences -> General -> Content Types -> (right side: Text -> HTML)
```

But this doesn't solve my problem. It would allow me to define new file extensions which Eclipse then would treat as HTML files, but I didn't find a place where I could define which files are XHTML files and which are normal HTML 4.01 or HTML 5 files.

There is a simple test to confirm that Eclipse in general is able to distinguish XHTML from HTML. Create two files with the following identical content:

```
<div class="Foo" />
```

Name one file test.html, the other one test.xhtml. If you open test.html, there will be a warning since the syntax above is not allowed in HTML (in my case, the code is underlined in yellow). If you open test.xhtml, there is no warning. So Eclipse must have seen (probably from the file extension) that the latter is an XHTML file.

How do I tell Eclipse that for another file extension?

By the way, I have installed the Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.8.0.

Comment: Does your document conform to the XHTML requirements, especially #2 and #3? https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#strict

Comment: @nitind Generally not. The respective documents contain fragments of (valid) XHTML code, but are not complete, valid documents on their own.